# ZeroMQ XSUB/XPUB proxy() API is not returning

Tags: zeromq, poco, poco-libraries

I have written a demo Windows service using POCO library.

As per POCO API the function `waitForTerminationRequest()` waits for a service termination request.

Now, in this POCO based windows service, I want to start a ZeroMQ library based Message Queue proxy to implement an XSUB/XPUB message queue.

More can be learnt here http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all.

For this I wrote another **`class ZeroMQProxy`**, which starts the proxy in the service's main function.

```
class ZeroMQProxy
{
private:
    zmq::context_t context;
    zmq::socket_t xsub;
    zmq::socket_t xpub;

public:
    ZeroMQProxy()
        : context(1),
        xsub(context, ZMQ_XSUB),        // Publisher End Proxy Sockets
        xpub(context, ZMQ_XPUB)         // Subscriber End Proxy Sockets
    {
    }

    ~ZeroMQProxy()
    {
    }

    void proxyopen()
    {
        xsub.bind("tcp://*:5559");
        xpub.bind("tcp://*:5560");

        zmq::proxy(xsub, xpub, nullptr);
    }

    void proxyclose()
    {
    }
};

class demopocoservice : public ServerApplication
{
private:
    bool _helpRequested;

public:
    demopocoservice() : _helpRequested(false)
    {
    }

    ~demopocoservice()
    {
    }

protected:
    void initialize(Application& self)
    {
        loadConfiguration();
        ServerApplication::initialize(self);
    }

    void uninitialize()
    {
        ServerApplication::uninitialize();
    }

    void defineOptions(OptionSet& options)
    {
        ServerApplication::defineOptions(options);

        options.addOption(
            Option("help", "h", "poco display help")
            .required(false)
            .repeatable(false)
            .callback(OptionCallback<demopocoservice>(
                this, &demopocoservice::handleHelp)));
    }

    void handleHelp(const std::string& name,
        const std::string& value)
    {
        _helpRequested = true;
        displayHelp();
        stopOptionsProcessing();
    }

    void displayHelp()
    {
        HelpFormatter helpFormatter(options());
        helpFormatter.setCommand(commandName());
        helpFormatter.setUsage("OPTIONS");
        helpFormatter.setHeader("poco: Zero message Queue.");
        helpFormatter.format(std::cout);
    }

    int main(const ArgVec& args)
    {
        if (!_helpRequested)
        {
            ZeroMQProxy zmqproxyObj;
            zmqproxyObj.proxyopen();

            waitForTerminationRequest();

            zmqproxyObj.proxyclose();
        }
        return Application::EXIT_OK;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Hello Poco ZMQ\n";

    demopocoservice pobj;
    pobj.run(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

My aim was when I start the service then the `zmq::proxy()` should have started the proxy and when I stop the service then proxy should be closed along with the sockets.

Problem is **`zmq::proxy()`** does not return back. 
So I am not able to stop the service.
Even if I do **`net stop <service name>`** the `waitForTerminationRequest()` does not receive termination request because of `zmq::proxy()`.

**What should I do to stop/close the proxy when I stop the service?**

Answer (score 1):

### ZeroMQ API confirms this:

> **Description**
>
> The `zmq_proxy()` function starts the built-in ØMQ proxy **in the current application thread**.
>   ...
>
> Before calling `zmq_proxy()` you must set any socket options, and connect or bind both *`frontend`* and *`backend`* sockets. The two conventional proxy models are:
>
> `zmq_proxy()` runs in the current thread and **returns only** if/when **the current context is closed**.

Given this fact, best instantiate an independent thread for leaving the proxy operate there and let the caller return so as to continue your other code-execution flows remain independent from the independent `zmq_proxy()` execution.

Another fair move would be to ( always ) set **`LINGER == 0`**, before any further steps and/or measures are with a newly instantiated sockets taken.

Comment: I had tried calling the proxy() in a poco runnable thread. But it did not help.

class ZMQThread : public Poco::Runnable
 void run()
 {
           ZeroMQProxy zmqproxyObj;
           zmqproxyObj.proxyopen();
 }

Called the above thread in service's main as:
   MQThread mqOne("Poco One", 4);
   Poco::Thread threadOne;
   threadOne.start(mqOne);
   threadOne.join();